# get pid of finished QProcess

Tags: python, pyqt, qprocess

I'm trying to get the PID of a finished QProcess, something like this:

```
proc = QProcess.start()
proc.finished.connect(self.finished)

def finished(self):
    self.sender().pid()
```

QProcess.pid() will return 0 if the process is [closed](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.7.2/doc/html/qprocess.html#pid) however, and QProcess.finished() would only call once the process is complete, so I can only ever get 0... How can I work around this? I'm trying to think of a way to NOT have to use the PID on completion, but at the moment that's what I have to do.

I tried `proc.aboutToClose.connect(self.finished)` but this never returned anything so it seems it wasn't signaled, but that would be a good solution if I can get that to work.

Comment: Use the `started()` signal to get the pid.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to get it at the end of the process. What I'm doing is updating a QTableView item to say "Completed" when the process completes and "Running..." while the process runs, etc. I use the PID to know which process has completed (there are an arbitrary number running at a time)

Comment: That makes no sense. By definition, a completed process does not have a pid. Use the `started()` signal to cache the pid on the process object (e.g. `proc.setObjectName(str(proc.pid()))`).

Comment: Nice that's exactly what I needed! I know it makes no sense (which is why I basically said so above) but I knew nothing about `setObjectName`. It's just what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ekhumoro gave the answer, the solution is to name the process by the PID and therefore you can still get it later by just querying the object name:

`proc.setObjectName(str(proc.pid()))`